# How to Pull a list of employees from Salesforce into C# program

Tags: sandbox, c#

I've finally achieved Logging into my Salesforce Sandbox using the C# program i wrote in VS2013.
Now im tweaking some things and i'm still new at this.

Basically my question is, How do i Pull already created users from the sandbox to my program and put each user in my List box?

the code i have currently doesnt do a whole lot and i cant find any other tutorials or code i can use.

```
        SforceService Sfdcbinding = null; 
        Lead updateLead = new Lead();

        updateLead.Id = Id;
        string newEmailAddress = txtEmail.Text;
        string newLastName = txtLastName.Text;
        updateLead.Email = newEmailAddress;
        updateLead.LastName = newLastName;

        SaveResult[] saveResults = Sfdcbinding.update(new sObject[] { updateLead });
```

Comment: I downvoted your question as there's a lot guides out there about accessing data with salesforce APIs in c# (SOAP in your case as I can see). All you have to do is perform query on User object and maybe cast the result from sObject to User type.

Comment: No idea how to do that. I havn't programmed in over a year.. (use it or lose it type thing) Got any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot specifically give detailed instructions in C# but here is you would do that in general.

1. You will first need to login to Salesforce using user's credentials (You can use [Partner Soap API login operation](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_login.htm) to do that).
2. Construct a SOQL query to get the list of users of your liking (you can query the data using [Partner API](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/) or [Salesforce REST API](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/)).
3. Parse the response, extract the user fields you looking for and populate the List box in the UI.